# Repeat bytes in Apple assembly?

Tags: ios, assembly

Is there a way to repeat the same series of bytes many time in Apple's assembler?

Example use-case: if I want to make an iPhone app with a gigabyte of NOP instructions in some function.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez that is not what I am asking about.

Comment: This would, be, for example, playing around to test how app size impacts various performance metrics.

Comment: My question explains perfectly well what I want to achieve. You just didn't trust that I had good motives for achieving it. I have given you one out of several possible.

Comment: why? what is unclear about the question as it stands? why would extraneous stuff like the motive help to understand it?

Comment: People who read your questions sometimes need more information in order to understand what you are up to.

Comment: With nested macros? Or some kind of `dup` directive in the assembly language?

Comment: It depends on the assembler, really

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I mean specifically the Apple assembler; i.e., the one that ships with OS X/clang/Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.fill](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/Assembler/040-Assembler_Directives/asm_directives.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000823-TPXREF153)

> `.fill 69, 4, 0xfeadface`
>   Generates 69 longs of value 0xfeadface

or [.space](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/Assembler/040-Assembler_Directives/asm_directives.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000823-TPXREF154)

> `ten_ones:  .space 10, 1`

when dealing with bytes only.

I couldn't find the equivalent of NASM `TIMES` that would let you repeat even instructions.

You can try to achieve that with recursive macros; I don't have access to Apple assembler, thus I can only sketch a possible macro.
Beware of syntax issues, expressiveness and arguments forwarding when dealing with (supposed) limited languages like that used for macros.

```
.macro TIMES
.if $0 > 0
    $1 
    var $0-1 $1
.endif
.endmacro

TIMES 100, mov
```

Comment: The gas manual has [an example of using a recursive macro to generate a variable-length block of whatever you want](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Macro.html).  The block could easily be instructions instead of `.long` or `.byte`.  Assuming Apple's assembler uses the same macro language / directives as GNU `as`, this should work.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks!

Comment: Btw, not being able to specifically do instructions is fine. I can just repeat the hex pattern of the instruction.